# GSON raises exception if object type is different

Tags: java, android, gson

I am using following approach to parse feed into Java Objects.

```
   val gsonBuilder = GsonBuilder()
        val gson = gsonBuilder.create()
        var homeModel: DataModel?=null

        try {
            homeModel = gson.fromJson(response, DataModel::class.java)
        }catch (ex:java.lang.Exception){
        }
```

This works fine if feed comes in the same format, but it type of some object changes it lands into exception block.

For example, feed some time provides "integers" instead of Object in "data"

```
@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private List<MoreData> data = null;
```

I want to know if there is any possibility in GSON to set specific data to "null" if type does not match.

Comment: In kotlin is easy but in Java I think is necessary to use serializeNulls method: Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();

Comment: @ManuelMato : I added ".serializeNulls()", but still getting, "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 11339 path $"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change your data type of "data" with List<**Object**> for **java** or List<**Any**> for **kotlin**. probably you will get rid of exception.

```
@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private List<Object> data = null;
```

but you will need to cast items to appropriate types while you are using.

For example:

```
val item:Int = homeModel[i] as Int //as yourDesiredType
```

However, if you want to set "data" null when data type is different, you can try:

```
val model = DataModel()
val json = Gson().toJson(model)
homeModel = Gson().fromJson(json, DataModel::class.java)
try {
        if(!homeModel.data.isNullOrEmpty()){
            homeModel.data.first() as String //as yourDesiredType
        }
} 
catch (ex:java.lang.Exception){
    homeModel.data = null
}
```

Comment: Thanks,  List<Object> seems better to avoid crash, can i know what type of data exists in   List<Object>, if its int, string or my model.

Comment: I think you can do that: if(!homeModel.data.isNullOrEmpty()){ if(homeModel.data.first() is String) {doSomething()} else {doAnotherThing()}
        }